# ToolStripControlHost hosting a UserControl designer Serializing won't occur

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms, serialization

I am currently developing an application in which I want to display a UserControl inside a context menu.  I was able to (somewhat achieve this using ToolStripControlHost).  Shown in (NumericUpDownToolStripItem code): below is code for the object (written in VC++.net 2.0). Note:  There are semi-similar SO questions on this, but none seem to be dealing with serializing usercontrols, just standard object in the usercontrols.

Shown following the object is the code for the actual usercontrol, which is a usercontrol with a label, and a numericupdown control.

The problem:  When I load the designer for my application, I can add my NumericUpDownToolStripItem just fine, however, when I open up the use the exposed propertly to edit my usercontrol, None of that data is serialized into the InitializeComponent method of my NumericUpDownToolStripItem object.  The effect of this is my control loads with all defaults at runtime.  And every time I reload my form, the modifications are lost.

I have tried using the TypeConverter tutorial located [On Msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typeconverter.aspx), but it didn't work properly.  Everything compiled just fine, except my object became completely greyed out in the design grid (just the accessor property, not the entire menupic).  Another problem I noticed is that this method isn't particularly designed for UserControls, which may have several different modifiable properties, and can't possibly have an overload for each.

**So, I have the following questions:**

1. Is what I'm doing practical, or is my structure way-off the norms.  I'm sure there are a lot of redundancy in the attributes.
2. What is the correct method to serialize a usercontrol 'child' contained in another UserControl\toolstriphost 'parent'.  Any properties in 'child' are simple values (Strings, Decimals, etc).
3. When the TypeConverter class Isn't implemented, every time I changed a property (a labels text for instance), the painting of the object would get all jacked up and behave strangely, until I releaded the context\menu or form.  Is there a proper way to inform the designer to repaint because I've made a change?  (I used invalidate which has been dodgy at best).

Thanks in advance.  I'm going to continue to research this and keep the question updated.

```
NumericUpDownToolStripItem Class:
    [ToolStripItemDesignerAvailability(ToolStripItemDesignerAvailability::All)]
    public ref class NumericUpDownToolStripItem : public ToolStripControlHost
    {
       public: 
       [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility::Content | 
          DesignerSerializationVisibility::Visible)]
       property LabeledNumericUpDown ^LabeledNumericUpDownControl
       {
         LabeledNumericUpDown ^get() { return (LabeledNumericUpDown^)this->Control; }
       }

       public: NumericUpDownToolStripItem(void) : 
          ToolStripControlHost(gcnew LabeledNumericUpDown()) {}

       protected: void OnSubscribeControlEvents(Control ^control) new  { //irrelevant to question }
       protected: void OnUnsubscribeControlEvents(Control ^control) new { //irrelevant to question }       
    };

public ref class LabeledNumericUpDown : public UserControl
{
   public: [ DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility::Content | 
    DesignerSerializationVisibility::Visible)]
   property String ^DisplayText {
      String ^get() {
         return this->label->Text;
      }
      void set(String ^val) {
         if(this->label->Text != val)
         {
            this->label->Text = val;
            this->Invalidate();
         }
      }
   }

//constructor
//destructor
//initiailecomponent
};
```

Comment: Sorry for the thread resurrection, but this seems to be the only post I can find dealing with this exact issue. I'm wondering what you did to make your control host designer visible - I can't seem to make visual studio display it, no matter what I do. I've applied everything that MSDN claims is supposed to enable designer support, and nothing. Some pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: I don't remember exactly what I did, but I know this control got released and is "in product".  I'm going to try to track down the code and repost the control itself to see if there is any difference.

Comment: Check my new post below, I reposted my current working setup

Comment: Thanks very much, that should be really helpful. This all stems from the annoying habit of the forms designer of either just quietly doing nothing if something fails, or crashing completely, instead of telling you what the problem is.

Comment: It works! Thanks a bunch. It took a bit of grappling with the C++ syntax, I'm not sure why you're using a FlowLayoutPanel, and I can't see what the CustomCodeDomSerializer is for, but it's now appearing in the designer. Thanks for your thorough example.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked.  The tablelayoutpanel thing was wierd.  The toolstripcontrol host couldn't natively add the usercontrol to the designer for some odd reason.  However, throwing it in a table, and then adding hte table would work fine.

Comment: I've thrown away the panel as it didn't appear to do anything at the time I was using it. My control host works fine with one of my controls - so I suggest that your TableLayoutPanel thing may be a red herring that's masking some other issue. If you're inclined to tweaking the code further, I'd be intrigued to know whether you can make it work without.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My most recent, "working" solution:

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///   <summary>   
///   This Usercontrol is a simple label coupled with a numericupdown.  The class following
///   it will wrap this item in toolstrip container so that it can be part of a contextmenu
///   </summary>
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
[DesignerSerializer(CustomCodeDomSerializer<LabeledNumericUpDown^>::typeid, CodeDomSerializer::typeid)]
public ref class LabeledNumericUpDown : UserControl
{
   public: event EventHandler ^NumericUpDownValueChanged;

   public: [Category("Custom Information"), Description(L"Text to display"), 
            DefaultValue(L"Default Text"), Browsable(true), Localizable(true), NotifyParentProperty(true)]
   property String ^DisplayText
   {
      String ^get();
      void set(String ^val);
   }

   public: [Category("Custom Information"), Description(L"NumericUpDown Value"), 
            DefaultValue(1), Browsable(true), Localizable(true), NotifyParentProperty(true)]
   property Decimal UpDownValue
   {
      Decimal get();
      void set(Decimal val);
   }

   public: [Category("Custom Information"), Description(L"NumericUpDown Maximum"), 
            DefaultValue(100), Browsable(true), Localizable(true), NotifyParentProperty(true)]
   property Decimal UpDownMaximum
   {
      Decimal get();
      void set(Decimal val);
   }

   public: [Category("Custom Information"), Description(L"NumericUpDown Minimum"), 
            DefaultValue(0), Browsable(true), Localizable(true), NotifyParentProperty(true)]
   property Decimal UpDownMinimum
   {
      Decimal get();
      void set(Decimal val);
   }

   private: bool SupressEvents;
   public: Void UpDownValueSet_NoEvent(int Val);
   private: Void numericUpDown_ValueChanged(Object ^sender, EventArgs ^e);
   public: LabeledNumericUpDown(void);
   private: System::Windows::Forms::NumericUpDown^  numericUpDown;
   private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label;
   private: System::Windows::Forms::TableLayoutPanel^  tableLayoutPanel1;
   private: System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;
   #pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
   void InitializeComponent(void);
};

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/// <summary>   CustomCodeDomSerializer
/// This is a specialized usercontrol designed to incapsulate another usercontrol (in this case a  
/// NumericUpDownToolStripItem.  In order to use this class, you must copy this entire class and 
/// create a new object.  (You can do this right underneath your usercontrol in the same file 
/// if you wish.  You must specifiy the type of your object every place its mentioned.
///   
/// To Note:  The toolbox bitmap is what the icon will look like.  You can specify any old control.
/// It is possible to use a custom icon, but I can't figure out how.
///</summary>
/// 
/// <value> The tool strip control host. </value>
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

[ToolStripItemDesignerAvailability(ToolStripItemDesignerAvailability::All),
 ToolboxBitmap(::NumericUpDown::typeid)]
public ref class NumericUpDownToolStripItem : ToolStripControlHost
{
   //replace this type
   private: LabeledNumericUpDown ^_Control;

   public: [Category("Object Host"), Description(L"Hosted usercontrol object"), 
    DisplayName("UserControl Object"), Browsable(true), NotifyParentProperty(true),
    DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility::Content)]
    //replace this properties type
   property LabeledNumericUpDown ^UserControlObject
   {
     //replace this properties return type
     LabeledNumericUpDown ^get() { return this->_Control; }
   } 

   public: NumericUpDownToolStripItem(void) : 
      System::Windows::Forms::ToolStripControlHost(gcnew FlowLayoutPanel())
   { 
      //replace this constructor type
      _Control = gcnew LabeledNumericUpDown();

      //don't touch this
      FlowLayoutPanel ^thePanel = (FlowLayoutPanel ^)this->Control;
      thePanel->BackColor = Color::Transparent;
      thePanel->Controls->Add(_Control);
   }   
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, after much searching, I found my answer.  My methodology was just fine, except for one major problem:  I didn't need typeconverters at all.  My problem was the need for a custom CodeDomConverter.  Shown below is my solution.

```
    generic<typename T>
    ref class CustomCodeDomSerializer : CodeDomSerializer
    {
    public: virtual Object ^Deserialize(IDesignerSerializationManager ^manager, Object ^codeObject) override
       {
          // This is how we associate the component with the serializer.
          CodeDomSerializer ^baseClassSerializer = (CodeDomSerializer^)manager->
             GetSerializer(T::typeid->BaseType, CodeDomSerializer::typeid);

           //This is the simplest case, in which the class just calls the base class
           //   to do the work. 
          return baseClassSerializer->Deserialize(manager, codeObject);
       }

       public: virtual Object ^Serialize(IDesignerSerializationManager ^manager, Object ^value) override
       {
           //Associate the component with the serializer in the same manner as with
           //   Deserialize 
          CodeDomSerializer ^baseClassSerializer = (CodeDomSerializer^)manager->
             GetSerializer(T::typeid->BaseType, CodeDomSerializer::typeid);

          Object ^codeObject = baseClassSerializer->Serialize(manager, value);

           //Anything could be in the codeObject.  This sample operates on a
           //   CodeStatementCollection. 
          if (dynamic_cast<CodeStatementCollection^>(codeObject))
          {
             CodeStatementCollection ^statements = (CodeStatementCollection^)codeObject;

             // The code statement collection is valid, so add a comment.
             String ^commentText = "This comment was added to this Object by a custom serializer.";
             CodeCommentStatement ^comment = gcnew CodeCommentStatement(commentText);
             statements->Insert(0, comment);
          }
          return codeObject;
       }

};




////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///   <summary>   
///   This Usercontrol is a simple label coupled with a numericupdown.  The class following
///   it will wrap this item in toolstrip container so that it can be part of a contextmenu
///   </summary>
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
[DesignerSerializer(CustomCodeDomSerializer<LabeledNumericUpDown^>::typeid, CodeDomSerializer::typeid)]
public ref class LabeledNumericUpDown : UserControl
{
   public: event EventHandler ^NumericUpDownValueChanged;

   public: [Category("Custom Information"), Description(L"Text to display"), 
            DefaultValue(L"Default Text"), Browsable(true), Localizable(true), NotifyParentProperty(true)]
   property String ^DisplayText
   {
      String ^get()
      {
         return this->label->Text;
      }
      void set(String ^val)
      {
         this->label->Text = val;
         if(this->DesignMode || 
            LicenseManager::UsageMode == LicenseUsageMode::Designtime) 
            this->Invalidate();

      }
   }
  //designer stuff not important
}




[ToolStripItemDesignerAvailability(ToolStripItemDesignerAvailability::All),
 ToolboxBitmap(::NumericUpDown::typeid)]
public ref class NumericUpDownToolStripItem : ToolStripControlHost
{
   //replace this type
   private: LabeledNumericUpDown ^_Control;

   public: [Category("Object Host"), Description(L"Hosted usercontrol object"), 
    DisplayName("UserControl Object"), Browsable(true), NotifyParentProperty(true),
    DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility::Content)]
    //replace this properties type
   property LabeledNumericUpDown ^UserControlObject
   {
     //replace this properties return type
     LabeledNumericUpDown ^get() { return this->_Control; }
   } 

   public: NumericUpDownToolStripItem(void) : 
      System::Windows::Forms::ToolStripControlHost(gcnew FlowLayoutPanel())
    { 
      //replace this constructor type
      _Control = gcnew LabeledNumericUpDown();

      //don't touch this
      FlowLayoutPanel ^thePanel = (FlowLayoutPanel ^)this->Control;
      thePanel->BackColor = Color::Transparent;
      thePanel->Controls->Add(_Control);
   }   
};
```